# Append Text to Textbox on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I currently have a selection of buttons and on click of a button I want to add the text from the button into a text-box. Every time I click on the button I want to be able to append on to whatever I have in the input field.

**What I currently have**

```
$('#js-AddFilterOpenBracket').click(function () {
    $('#js-FilterString').val($(this).text());
});
```

**What I'm Aiming for**

```
$('#js-AddFilterOpenBracket').click(function () {
    $(this).text().appendTo($('#js-FilterString'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `appendTo` as it should be used for elements. Rather, manually append to the current value then set it

```
$('#js-AddFilterOpenBracket').click(function () {
    var currentVal = $('#js-FilterString').val();
    var newVal = currentVal + $(this).text();
    $('#js-FilterString').val(newVal);
});
```

Comment: Works great, Thank you. Will mark as answer in 10 mins :)

Answer (score 1):

May not be the bast way but you could do this

```
$('#js-AddFilterOpenBracket').click(function () {
    $('#js-FilterString').val($('#js-FilterString').val() + $(this).text());
});
```